# Eclipse dynamic web project run on tomcat get 404 (page not found) error

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, gradle

After migrate to eclipse 4.5 (mars), I  imported my project from remote git repository. Added tomcat 7 server to eclipse servers list. And tried to run project on server, but get 404 error. I use gradle as build tool.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

war.archiveName "gepick.war"

dependencies {
   compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.1'
   //...... list of libs

   runtime 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.2'
}

war {
    from 'WebContent' 
}

task copyTask(type: Copy) {
    from 'build/libs/gepick.war'
    into '/opt/tomcat/webapps/'
}
```

Eclipse Web deployment assembly: http://postimg.org/image/kq5h1dol9/

 Server settings: http://postimg.org/image/ohrcpuirb/

For me is strange why deployed project on deploy path has only folders without .class files on /../.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/gepick/WEB-INF/classes.

I read other posts but not found way how to fix it. Where I should look to search the problem?

Comment: Have you generated the eclipse files with gradle?

Comment: I added gradle build file to post. I dont know what gradle do on eclipse, if I good understood gradle only collect needed dependenies on eclipse to lib folder.

Comment: Not sure if it will fix your issue, but I would use `apply plugin: 'eclipse'` to generate the eclipse build files, at least. Then we can see from there.

Comment: Added `apply plugin: 'eclipse'`  but it not fixed for my issue.

Comment: You also have to make sure that the gradle task `eclipse` gets called at some point. You can do it via eclipse gradle plugin or via command line in the project root folder like this: `gradle eclipse`

Comment: I tried `gradle eclipse` command on root project folder, and got :

BUILD SUCCESSFUL, but problem still exist

Comment: Fixed for me `apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'` on build.gradle  file

Comment: Great! Feel free to answer your own question in the form below, so others can benefit from your solution.