# What is dedicated .org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.javascriptValidator.launch file on eclipse project .externalToolBuilders folder?

Tags: eclipse

I have problem to deploy my project to run on tomcat server on Eclicpse IDE after when it imported from git repository. And nowhere I can find the problem. Now I am looking into the project folder structure and found  .externalToolBuilders folder with .org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.javascriptValidator.launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.ant.AntBuilderLaunchConfigurationType">
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_BUILDER_ENABLED" value="false"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_DISABLED_BUILDER" value="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.javascriptValidator"/>
<mapAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_TOOL_ARGUMENTS"/>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_TRIGGERS_CONFIGURED" value="true"/>
</launchConfiguration>
```

I want to know what this file do and or it can has the influence for my problem?

Comment: What *is* the problem you're having?

Comment: I described on this post my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968773/eclipse-dynamic-web-project-run-on-tomcat-get-404-page-not-found-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a launch configuration file for an Ant Builder. It looks like this builder is disabled. Builders are listed in the 'Builders' tab on the Project Properties dialog.

It is unlikely that this is causing whatever problem you are having.